# How can I set Bot names by team?

Tags: counter-strike

I know how to change names of bots but is there a way in which I could write names of bots separately for terrorists and c.terrorists so the names don't jumble up.

I also want to ask about, in the same file, "bots profile," in front of the gun's name 't' is written. Does 't' stands for terrorist and mean that the name is only used for terrorists?

For example:
Easy sniper't' rick
Skin 1.........
.................. ... .......

Answer (score 1):

No, T stands for preferred weapon that they use, not always join terrorist; there is no way to do that. You only can use command to spawn them specifically... or maybe a plugin out there